# Make: Permission Denied (until I `cd .`)

Tags: freebsd, make

I have an account on a shared host running FreeBSD 5.5-STABLE.  I was compiling my own version of Ruby today, and encountered this anomaly: If I tried to execute 'make', I get a "permission denied" error.  However, if I execute:

```
cd .
```

And then

```
make
```

Everything work just fine.  Any clue why this happens? It obviously isn't causing me problems as I am eventually able to execute make just fine, but I am very curious what is going on here.

Comment: What was your working directory before, then after, the "cd ."?

Comment: @Bart I had downloaded the Ruby source to ~/src, and unpacked the tar.gz from there, so it was something like ~/src/ruby-01.8.7/, and I was operating directly from inside the unpacked ruby source directory.

Comment: Was there a permission difference in the directories you were in before and after the "cd ."?

Comment: @Bart - I'm not sure I follow.  Wouldn't a 'cd .' just say 'change directory to current directory', in which case the permissions before and after are the same, since no chmod was done in conjunction?  the ~/src is 755, and ~/src/ruby-1.8.7 is 755 as well (and both owned by my user)

Comment: Could potentially do a difference if there are/were symlinks in the path before/after the `cd .`, but that does sound strange.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. I was just asking just in case it wasn't behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe it's FreeBSD (weird) bug (or just my lack of knowledge about BSD ports/shell). Look at [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=118730&cat=).

Comment: A bug from 2007? Really? :-/

Comment: @Bart it is a very old shared host.  Or rather, a very old account on a host previously known as TextDrive that was later purchased by Joyent.  The account is a grandfathered account and the system is probably as old as the account, circa 2006/2007

Comment: Though it does seem rather odd that a 'make' bug could make it into any stable release

Comment: Bug mentioned above was closed as bogus because it was caused by missing `x` bit in /home directory rights.

Comment: BTW, I think that removing `x` bit from /home directory is pretty common on shared hosting so that users denied access to each other home directories.